# Creating a blob representation of a csv file on my machine using Salesforce Apex code

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

Can anyone tell me how to create a blob representation of csv file on my machine using Apex code? I am trying to upload a csv file programmatically using Apex custom class. I am using custom classes installed by product AWS s3 which i have installed on SalesForce. I am calling the function syncFilesystemDoc in AWS_S3_ExampleController.cls. To use this correctly i need to populate fileblob, which is where i am stuck.

[Edit] This code dos not have a UI. I am not looking for a UI related solution

regards

Sameer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A blob is just a Binary Large OBject, it's just the binary data. I don't know what language you're using but you just need to load the entire file into memory and put it in the appropriate parameter.

What are you developing in? Apex only runs on the force.com platform, so you can't use that locally on your machine.

Comment: Yep i was trying to do something dumb :(. Trying to figure out how to load the entire "local" file. What i need to to do is create a string of the Sdfc object which i want to save in S3 and create a blob of that string using Blob.valueOf()

Answer (score 0):

According the the salesforce documents, the Blob data type has a valueof() that will convert from a string to Blob

See http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/langCon_apex_primitives.htm or http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_blob.htm

so

```
String csvFile = 'field1,field2,field3\n';
csvFile += '1value1,1value2,1value3\n';
csvFile += '2value1,2value2,2value3';
Blob csvBlob = Blob.valueOf(csvFile);
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: Yep, thanks. I was trying to figure out how to load file contents in a string, which was the wrong approach.